# This site can't be reached 192.168.0.104 localhost refused to connect

Tags: git

So I am using ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I try to run the clone(`git clone`) project using Visual Studio (VS) Code, I face below error. I face this error only on git clone projects

> dev
> webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js

Project running at:

- http://192.168.0.104:8080
- http://localhost:8080
  node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
  at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
  at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
  at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:144:18)
  at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:46:50)
  at OriginalSource.updateHash (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/OriginalSource.js:104:8)
  at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:753:17)
  at handleParseResult (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:817:10)
  at /home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:908:4
  at processResult (/home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:640:11)
  at /home/shubham/Projects/Three/threejs-dc-1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:692:5 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
  }

Node.js v18.2.0

Comment: 192.168 is a private network space, so the mapping 192.168.0.104 is something you must set up. This is a network setup question, suitable for superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You run the command in Ubuntu terminal

```
git clone https://projectlink.com
```

Comment: I am facing this issue after cloning

Comment: do you run npm install command after clone ?

Comment: and try to run the after cloning and npm install command with live server extension.

Comment: You might be connected to a different router, or some other internet connection. So, you will have to check on that as well and ensure that you are connected with the same router via ethernet or Wi-Fi that you are trying to access.
if not working then change the browser and also apply restart the system.

Comment: I do run npm install after cloning and I have changed the browser as well and restarted my system. and I have connected same wifi that I was trying to access but haven't found the solution yet.